# How does 7-Zip determine tar file order on Windows?

Tags: windows, tar, 7-zip

For unix-like systems, [`tar` uses `readdir()`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120143/how-is-the-order-in-which-tar-works-on-files-determined). What does 7-Zip use on Windows to determine tar file order?